# PHP | Getting JSON data from URL and putting it to a array shows only 1 item?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to grab some JSON data from URL and then trying to put it into a array and then echo it out to a webpage. What am I doing wrong?

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$items = $data["rgDescriptions"];

foreach($items as $item){
    $data2 = [
    'market_hash_name' => $item["market_hash_name"],
    'price' => 0,
    'permission' => 'both_side'
    ];
}

echo json_encode($data2);
```

Comment: add var_dump after every statement and see.

do var_dump($json) before you decode it, var_dump($data) after your decode. Then do var_dump($items).

Comment: You are overwriting your variable in the loop...

Comment: 4 times the same answer. xD

Comment: And one comment: Do `array_push($data2,[]);` ;---)

Comment: @Anant Don't abuse code formatting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting your $data2 variable every time the loop goes through.
Declare you array outside of the loop and add each element in a new key of your array.

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$items = $data;
$data2 = [];

foreach($items as $item){
    $data2[] = [
    'market_hash_name' => $item["market_hash_name"],
    'price' => 0,
    'permission' => 'both_side'
    ];
}

echo json_encode($data2);
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will accept your answer right away, but I have one question. Is there possible to "split" lists? To make example max if the data is 1000 different items, then only 500 of them will make it to data2?

Comment: Yes there is different ways to do this. I would just break out of the foreach loop after the maximum number of results I want in $data2 is reached.

Answer (score 5):

In your case $data2 variable is overwritten in loop. So it will just store last record in your array. Declare it as array and add each record in a key of that array.

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$items = $data["rgDescriptions"];
$data2 = []; // create empty array.
foreach($items as $item){
    $data2[] = [
        'market_hash_name' => $item["market_hash_name"],
        'price' => 0,
        'permission' => 'both_side'
    ];
}

echo json_encode($data2);
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are over-writing `$data2` variable again and again inside `foreach()` loop

Solution:-

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$items = $data["rgDescriptions"];
$data2 = array(); // create an empty array
foreach($items as $item){
    $data2[] = [
    'market_hash_name' => $item["market_hash_name"],
    'price' => 0,
    'permission' => 'both_side'
    ]; // assign value to array
}

echo json_encode($data2); // encode the array finally
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell php to add new values to new arrays :

```
foreach($items as $item){
    $data2[] = [
        'market_hash_name' => $item["market_hash_name"],
        'price' => 0,
        'permission' => 'both_side'
    ];
}
```

Comment: this is correct too (a bit more explanation needed).btw+1